# How to use the same spark context in a loop in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `shell script` that invokes a `pyspark` job and creates tables in Hive. The script works fine. Now want to reduce the time taken for the script to run while invoking as `cron jobs` for more than `100 tables`.

The `import.sh` script is below.

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/$USER/source.sh

[ $# -ne 1 ] && { echo "Usage : $0  table "; exit 1; }

table=$1

TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log
success_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
failed_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log

function log_status
{
       status=$1
       message=$2
       if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | tee -a "${failed_logs}"
                #echo "Please find the attached log file for more details"
                exit 1
                else
                    echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [INFO] $message [Status] $status : success" | tee -a "${success_logs}"
                fi
}

#Executing Spark job with python script
spark-submit --name "SparkJob" --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 4g --num-executors 3 --conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=709" --conf "spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=209"   /home/$USER/import.py ${table} ${mysqldb} ${hivedb} ${domain} ${port} ${username} ${password}

g_STATUS=$?
log_status $g_STATUS "SPARKJOB ${table} EXECUTION"

echo "*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-"
```

The `import.py` pyspark script is below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

#Condition to specify exact number of arguments in the spark-submit command line
if len(sys.argv) != 8:
     print "Invalid number of args......"
     print "Usage: spark-submit file.py Input_path Output_path"
     exit()
table=sys.argv[1]
mysqldb=sys.argv[2]
hivedb=sys.argv[3]
domain=sys.argv[4]
port=sys.argv[5]
username=sys.argv[6]
password=sys.argv[7]

#Get table from MYSQL as a Data Frame into Spark
df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "{}:{}/{}".format(domain,port,mysqldb)).option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","{}".format(table)).option("user", "{}".format(username)).option("password", "{}".format(password)).load()

df.registerTempTable('mytempTable')

# Create Table in Hive using the temptable
sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`{}` as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))

sc.stop()
```

I am getting the desired results with my above scripts.

I am able to get data from `MYSQL` database to `PYSPARK` and then able to create tables in `HIVE`. Also I am able to collect the logs for each `sparkjob`.

For example I have 100 tables to import from `MYSQL` to `HIVE`.

I am scheduling this shell script as a cronjob. This shell script will run 10 times in parallel in a loop.

I mean `./import.sh table1`, `./import.sh table2`,`./import.sh table3`,`./import.sh table4` and so on 10 times

**`Now my question`**

Each time the shell script is invoked a spark context is being opened. It takes around 10-12 seconds for a spark context to open. Now at the end we are closing the spark context using `sc.stop()`.

So If I want to run the script I have to open 100 spark context and close them after completing the job.

What I want is instead of closing the `spark context` after completion of the job, Can we reuse the same `sparkContext` for another table in loop.

I mean when I do this `./import.sh table1` I want to use the `sparkcontext` that was opened in this job for the table that comes next in the loop. I mean for the `table 11`.

Is this possible?

If yes then How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It si possible to do, but you need to change some process.

The easy way is to install the Spark Job Server ([Git](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver)).

This will allow you to submit multiple spark jobs, and with proper configuration even share DataFrames between applications.

I suggest you to go with this.